# How can I get the param passed in an URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework

I have some datatables and I want to get the param id 194 out of the URL

```
admin/customer-management/updater/id/194
```

My source AJAX:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/<?= Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage(); ?>/admin/CustomerManagement/getlistcontactsajax/idCustomer/" + $(this).attr('value');
```

I do this `+ $(this).attr('value');` but it does not work.

Comment: do you want to get the `id` from URL ?

Comment: You need to rewrite your question. What is $(this)? i.e. what event on what element are you accessing attr("value") which would likely be .val() in real jQuery and what does it have to do with the URL? Do you mean `location.href.split("/").pop()`

Comment: `"admin/customer-management/updater/id/194".split("/").pop()`

Comment: i want to get this param to add in url ajaxsource to get the datatables

Comment: Is `admin/customer-management/updater/id/194` the path of your page URL? or a variable you defined?

Answer (score 2):

Visibly, you use PHP (with Zend) to write your js code.
You can recover the id in your controller with :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

So you can write your js code with it (may be pass variable in the view):

```
"sAjaxSource": "/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/CustomerManagement/getlistcontactsajax/idCustomer/<?= $id?>",
```

Comment: yes but i have the param in other function in the same controller how can i do the request from this function updatercustom(),thanks for you

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If updatercustom() generate id, in you action, you can do `$this->view->id = $this->updatercustom();` and in your view, you can use `$this->id` parameter

Comment: so i have in this finction that :`public function updatecustomerAction()
    {
     $idCustomer = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam( 'idCustomer' );`but i want get the param in this function  ` public function getlistcontactsajaxAction()
    {
     $contacts = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact();
     
     
     $idCustomer=what can id here for getparam the other function `thanks for help

Comment: Where are you write `"sAjaxSource": "/<?= Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage(); ?>/admin/CustomerManagement/getlistcontactsajax/idCustomer/"` ? In the view of `updatecustomerAction`? In the view of `getlistcontactsajaxAction`? elsewhere?

Comment: in the view of updatecustomeraction because i need in the view of updatecustomer  thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. :) In the `updatecustomeraction()` you recover the customer id with `$idCustomer = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam( 'idCustomer' );` and you pass it in the view like this : `$this->view->idCustomer = $idCustomer `. In the view, you can use the id like this: `"sAjaxSource": "/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/CustomerManagement/getlistcontactsajax/idCustomer/<?= $this->idCustomer?>",` which is a part of js to call `getlistcontactsajaxAction()` with ajax (If I'm not mistaken) :)

Comment: it's not work when i do var_dump($this->idCustomer?> it's give NULL

Comment: No it's not null in the URL if you have teamviewer you can show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76558/discussion-between-doydoy44-and-user3791255).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the url variable you could do you could use the regex `url.match(/\d+$/)` to fetch it

Answer (score 1):

you could do this by:

```
parseInt(location.href.split("/").pop())
```

or

```
parseInt(location.href.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, ""))
```

Comment: Why parseint? It is a string to be used as a string

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, given the unclear question.

`location.href` will give you the current page URL. In your case (again, my assumption), it's `admin/customer-management/updater/id/194`

Hence, do the following.

```
var ID = location.href.split("/").pop();
```

The above creates an array, like below and then assigns the last item in the array to the variable `ID`

```
["admin", "customer-management", "updater", "id", "194"]
```

You can then do:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/<?=Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale')->getLanguage();?>/admin/CustomerManagement/getlistcontactsajax/idCustomer/" + ID
```

Comment: Looks very close to what I suggested but did not answer since there was not enough information to see what he meant.